# Trying to filter greater than or equal to (>=) -50%

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter in the array collection of row the rate having greater than or equal to -50% to easily identify as the "degraded" row.

Code:

```
$SumTPNR = 0
$SumPPNR = 0

foreach ($Row in $table) {
    $html += try {
        $Rate = [DECIMAL](100*(($Row.NumOfPNRs-$Row.PreviousWeekNumOfPNRs)/$Row.PreviousWeekNumOfPNRs))
        $Rate = "{0:N0}" -f $Rate
        $ErrorTrapped = $error[0].Exception.Message -eq "Attempted to divide by zero."

        "<tr>
        <td>" + $Row[0] + "</td>
        <td>" + $Row[1] + "</td>
        <td>" + $Row[2] + "</td>"

        if ($Rate -ge -50) {
            if ($Rate -ne $ErrorTrapped) {
                "<td>" +  "$Rate % Degraded" + " </td></tr>"
            }
        } else {
            "<td>" +  "$Rate %" + " </td></tr>"
        }
    } catch {
        "<td>" + "$Null" + "</td></tr>" 
    }

    $SumTPNR += $Row[1] -join '+'
    $SumPPNR += $Row[2] -join '+' 
}
```

Output:

[image: Sample Screenshot of the Output]

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this line?

```
$Rate = "{0:N0}" -f $Rate
```

You're converting `$Rate` into a string, but trying to do a greater than comparison with a number - which I believe will covert the number to a string and do an ordinal string comparison between the two. Remove that line.

*Original answer, for posterity:*

<s>Working through the first row...</s>

((6 - 1) / 1) * 100 = 500

500 is greater than -50

So I would expect it to hit the first condition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Rex. Not sure if my condition is correct but I was trying to get the all the degraded rate values.

Here's a sample of the array
Rate
-10,
-20,
-30,
-40,
-50,
-60,
-70,
-80,
0,
500,

My desired output should only filter these values
Rate
-50,
-60,
-70,
-80,

Can you help me to correct the condition?

Comment: If 500 is passing the condition, which means 500 is greater than -50, and that's not what you want, what do *you* think your condition should be?

Comment: Sorry, am new in PS and running out of ideas on how to correct or what condition to use.I even used -le operator but the resut is different. Your advice on how to correct it will be a big help.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Cool! I removed that line, used -le operator instead and got the right result. Thank you very much for the advice. Greatly appreciated! =)